# How to remove/disable the insertion of a driver added with depmod -a?

Tags: centos, drivers, kernel-modules

I added my custom driver to be inserted automatically at boot using:

```bsh
cp ./driver/mydrv.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra/
depmod -a
```

Now I'd like to update with a new version of the driver, I launched the same command but the previous version is inserted...

`find /lib/modules -type f -name *mydrv*` I removed all the existing files.

- How can I debug that?
- How can I check from which file the driver is loaded at boot?
- How can I check the driver file used? (`lsmod` doesn't give anything useful but the size and if used)

It seems I can't stop the load of that old third-party driver.

FYI: Running `rmmod/insmod` the new driver is successfully loaded.

*CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003*

Comment: Maybe you need to rebuild your initrd?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I gave up and reinstalled the OS. I'll try next time if that happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stoney said, **initramfs** has to be regenerated. The reason of the corruption is unknown.

1. Remove all the ***.ko** to remove in **weak-updates** folder.
2. Generate **initramfs**: `dracut -f --regenerate-all` for Centos/RHEL/Fedora